# apply conditional style in angular 2

Tags: angular, styles, conditional-statements

I am trying to apply conditional styles for example, there is obsolete property in user, if a user's obsolete is true, I would like to add `<del>` like below. I searched internet, but I don't know well what is the best way. I know that `*ngIf`, so I could use it, but I think there is more smart way. If someone used to this, could you please let me know?

```html
<tr *ngFor="let user of pagedItems">
           <td align="left">{{user.name}}</td>
           <td align="left">{{user.age}}</td>
</tr>


<tr *ngFor="let user of pagedItems">
           <td align="left"><del>{{user.name}}</del></td>
           <td align="left"><del>{{user.age}}</del></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do the following:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let user of pagedItems">
    <td align="left">
        <span [class.obselete]="user.obsolete">{{user.name}}</span>
    </td>
    <td align="left">
        <span [class.obselete]="user.obsolete">{{user.age}}</span> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

This would apply the css class `.obselete` to the text if your `user.obsolete = true`.

CSS for line-through:

```css
    .obselete { 
        text-decoration: line-through; 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Could I ask quick question? If I do not want to define my own css, instead I want to borrow <del> from bootstrap, it has the effect to put the line in the middle of string, {{user.name}}. Is there any way I can acheive it? I am not that accustomed to use customized css. So.. Thank you for your answer again.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to conditionally use `<del>` without hiding the text within the tags. Are you using separated html and css template files? I have edited the answer to include the css code you would need.

Comment: I see, I think it can be applied. Thank you so much!

Comment: Regardless of user.obsolete value, it put line-through :) Do you have any idea? I think it may be my fault. But I think I followed the way you suggested :)

Comment: It does not get the value properly, when I get the value directly as component's property for example, I put the variable isLineThrough then I switch that variable between true and false, it worked well accordingly. but in my actual source, it refer to user.obsolete.. it does not work. I do not know why. I print out the value, value is correctly set.

Comment: Just in case, it is because of variable type, actually, the user.obsolete value is not defined as boolean explicitly.